# use of unresloved identifier FIRMessaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm facing a strange issue during integration of the Firebase Notification new API in my iOS Swift App.
I encounter some difficulties receiving a push Notification sent from the Firebase web plateform. My certificate is OK since I tested it with a quick PHP script to send a test notification to my phone.

In this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37467793/5082848 , it is said to add in AppDelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { error in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

However, **FIRMessaging is unknown**, whereas my podfile correctly contains Firebase/Messaging . Here is what the terminal returns after pod install :

Using Firebase (3.3.0)

Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.1)

Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.7)

Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)

Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)

Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)

**Do you have any clue please ? Thanks a lot**

Comment: You need to add this in AppDelegate: "import Firebase"

Comment: do you run `app.xcodeproj` or `app.xcworkspace` ?

Comment: upgrading from 3.2 to 3.3 seems to have broken notifications for me

Answer (score 32):

You should import FirebaseMessaging

```
import FirebaseMessaging
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks but I tried to have a look into imports but there is no FirebaseMessaging ... I only have Firebase, FirebaseStorage, FirebaseAuth

Answer (score 25):

Downgrading from 3.3 to 3.2 fixed the problem for me. To get the messenger library you have to install it's pod separately.

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Answer (score 20):

Open your podfile

1. add : pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
2. install/update the pod
3. add: import FirebaseMessaging in your AppDelegate

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay then,

It seems to be a bad pod install since I tried to create from an all new project with the same podfile and I had many new return lines including :
`Installing FirebaseMessaging (1.1.0)`

I'll try to uninstall all pods and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the top

```
import Firebase
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your project/ ProjectNavigator/Pods.xcodeproj/Targets and check if there is a FirebaseMessaging in your pods list.
If not open Pods file and add "pod 'Firebase/Messaging' " and run "pod install" into the terminal.

Comment: This has already been suggested in previous answers.