# Sending Push Notifications to IOS Devices with php

Tags: php, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on and IOS App that will send push notifications with FCM, i've configured everything right on the FCM Console and tested sending a message from the console to the device and it worked. Now i'm using the below script and the message is not able to push to the phone. 
When i send i get this message

```
{"multicast_id":7893466200486146313,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1506525095628728%b54fead7f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Below is my script

```
// Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "-------";
// Replace with the real client registration IDs
$registrationIDs = array('00000');
// Message to be sent
$message = "New Message from GWCL";
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( 'message' => $message,'title' => "New Message",'notId'=>''.time(), 'complain_id'=>'90','push'=>'reply','priority'=>'high'),
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
// Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

I followed a tutorial which told me to  add `'priority'=>'high'`, i did but still didn't work

Comment: make sure you have proper registration device token from ios and as per your response from php there is no error.may be from ios device you have to check.

Comment: also if its success it means you have proper device token or else it will throw invalid registration

Comment: I've not used FCM, but are you in Release or Debug? If you are debugging then you must use a debug certificate and instruct FCM to connect to Apple debug APNs.

Comment: I’ve uploaded the .p12 file to fcm

Comment: Only VoIP Push certificate is same for Debug and Release. Normal Push certificates are different.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i worked on Push notification on both Firebase and APN so i can say as per your FCM response Push notification sent successfully from PHP end

so  I guess you are handling some think wrong in your app side

As i am PHP developer i am not much aware of ios development.so can share some  links it might help you to debug

[firebase iOS not receive push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430649/firebase-ios-not-receive-push-notifications)

[Firebase when receive Push Notification did not receive the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458530/firebase-when-receive-push-notification-did-not-receive-the-popup)

[iOS not receiving Firebase Push Notification sent through the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152764/ios-not-receiving-firebase-push-notification-sent-through-the-api)

[Not receiving Push Notifications Using firebase and Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227220/not-receiving-push-notifications-using-firebase-and-objective-c)

[Not receiving Firebase push notifications when app is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362934/not-receiving-firebase-push-notifications-when-app-is-open)

Comment: I am facing almost similar problem
My server sending data message to a topic, it is working in Android but unable to receive in IOS, on other hand when I send message from firebase console then IOS works well, what my guess is, server sending data message in a format that IOS not supporting may be wrong key value pairs etc, can you please tell me that what should be the format of data message that I want to receive in IOS, or there is predefined keys that server side need to use.